# Access static variable value from C++ lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Just for the sake of learningship, I was wondering if I could access a static variable created within a lambda. If that is possible, how would it be done?

Due to how lambdas are defined, I imagine that even if I could access the functor object derived from the lambda, I would still not able to access static variables created within the scope of operator(). Anyways, I have tried the below and it did not work:

```
int main()
{
    auto lamda = []() { static int count; count++; };
    // std::cout << decltype(lambda)::count << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried the snippet above and it did not work.

Comment: You can't access a static variable inside of a normal function either. (That's the point of scoping it to the function in the first place)

Comment: How about returning it? What is the underlying problem you think this would solve?

Comment: It's **not** a static member of the class. It's a static function variable. It has the same scope rules as a static function variable. The only way to accesses it is by returning it as the result of the function.

Comment: Please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391058/how-do-static-variables-in-lambda-function-objects-work

Comment: [Can I access static variables inside a function from outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30635953/can-i-access-static-variables-inside-a-function-from-outside) which explains **you can't.** See also  [How do static variables in lambda function objects work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391058/how-do-static-variables-in-lambda-function-objects-work)